# After the mnist training set and the test set image are normalized, the training accuracy is extremely low

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression, mnist

I want to classify the handwritten numbers in MNIST based on tensorflow, but after normalizing the pixels between the training set and the test set, the accuracy of the training set is extremely low!

Please help me figure out the reason, the code is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Load the MNIST dataset
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('original_data/', one_hot=True)

# Define model inputs and outputs
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# Define variables and models
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=y_pred))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Define the evaluation function
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Normalization treatment
train_images = mnist.train.images / 255.0
test_images = mnist.test.images / 255.0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for epoch in range(20):
        # Training model
        for i in range(55000):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

        # Print the accuracy on the training set and test set
        train_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: train_images, y: mnist.train.labels})
        test_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_images, y: mnist.test.labels})
        print("Epoch %d: train accuracy %f, test accuracy %f" % (epoch+1, train_acc, test_acc))
```

The output of the code is as follows:

[image: Output of code]

I tried to comment out the normalized code

That is, remove the code：

```py
train_images = mnist.train.images / 255.0 
test_images = mnist.test.images / 255.0
```

and train with a non-normalized training set and a test set.

The result shows that the accuracy is about 0.9 on the training set. I do not know why the accuracy after picture normalization is so low.

Please, help me figure this out.